# Kanban View and Required dependent picklist

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, dependent-picklist, kanban

We have a picklist called Reasons. It is a required field.

We use it for determining reasons Won and Lost. The values for each of these are different so we use standard dependency between Stage and Reasons. (This seems pretty standard)

The issue is that there are no reasons for any other stages and the Kanban view doesn't allow us to move Opportunities as it presents the Dependent Picklist in a dialog but there is nothing to select.

Thoughts? Do we need to do this is a different way for lightning?